# How can I start writing the code of a OPC UA Client in Arduino IDE to use it in ESP32?

Tags: automation, arduino, opc, esp32

I am new to OPC UA concept. I understand the principles of it but when it comes to practical aspects I have a problem. I want to send a number to OPC UA Server using ESP32 module. ESP32 should be programmed in Arduino IDE. How can I start writing the code? I try to google it but there is nothing I found. Does anyone know how I can proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I think the OPC UA has nothing to do with your problem.

You need to download the [Arduino IDE](https://www.arduino.cc).

Since this is made for the Arduino (ATMega boards), you have to install an extension or plugin to compile your code for the ESP32.

Just googling Arduino and ESP32, you find the entire documentation for it:
[arduino-esp32](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32) You will find a guide, step for step, how to install the ESP32 board in the Arduino IDE.

Once you updated your settings in the Arduino IDE, you can find the ESP boards and you can begin to develop what you want.

But if you are new and you don't know how it works, maybe you should begin to read some documentation in the [Guide section](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/HomePage)

It is important that you understand how Arduino use the libraries, since this is one of the powerfull feature in this IDE.